# React + Node - Unable to upload image to S3

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload image from react using AWS SDK.

The process I'm following:

> **Get a signed URL from backend (returns 200)**

> **Use PUT request using the returned signed url (returns 400 error)**

```
// returns the file name which will be uploaded and the signed url
    const uploadConfig = await axios.get('/api/upload/image/sign');
// upload the actual file
    await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, image, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': image.type
      }
    });
```

## Error

```
Request URL: https://<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/5f8879747732900023eef381/e87a4a2f-b58b-478c-9d1b-fe769233ed20.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=<access_key>&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1602781066&Signature=Kj15gko%2BYoqz212#4GuOFDc12D8$%^
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 53.213.67.151:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

> **S3 bucket cors config :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

> **S3 Policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1602682508288",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1602682506434",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue regarding S3 Policy. Try to attach the PutObject or (*) policy to your S3 bucket.
If not working check your sign generation endpoint and result.

The more information You can find [here](https://medium.com/@aakashbanerjee/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-the-browser-using-pre-signed-urls-4602a9a90eb5)